# "My private folder" alternative

Tags: software-rec, private-data

I'm looking for an alternative for the now defunct My Private Folder solution from Microsoft. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/).

Also, I've never used it but [AxCrypt](http://www.axantum.com/AxCrypt/) seems like it might be easier to manage.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider [FreeOTFE](http://www.freeotfe.org/index.html); it also provides [On-The-Fly-Encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OTFE) (as per TrueCrypt) but has an additional "Explorer" program that allows its OTFE volumes to be accessed on machines without admin rights.

The latter is useful to me because I use it to keep (almost) everything on my USB stick safe in case I lose it, while still being able to decrypt things while on machines I don't control (i.e. so I can continue working on assignments when in labs at Uni).

**Warning** - it has issues RE a lack of driver signing on 64bit Windows, they are a little awkward to work around, so I cannot really recommend it in the case you have a 64bit Windows OS.
*(Although I'm using it on 64Bit Win7 at home, but that's not the point - I'm happy to work around the issues, you might not be).*

Comment: the person that needs the solution uses a 64Bit Windows 7 and it's not that technical, so i think this might be an issue, but thanks anyway!